# Eigenvalues decrease with power

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-norm

Take $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and consider a square matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$, with real and positive entries, and such that $\|A\|_2 \leq 1$.

I think the following statement holds from simulation, but fail to show that it is true.

$p \mapsto \lambda_i(A^p(A^T)^p)$ is non-increasing when $p$ increases, where $\lambda_i(\cdot)$ is the $i$-th largest eigenvalue (in complex norm).

Comment: I deleted my first answer as I saw the mistake, let me think about it a bit more.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Here is a thought, but I am not sure it is correct: $A^p$ will somehow contract the space as $p$ grows, same for $(A^T)^p$, and the multiplication of both can only contract it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$x^TA^{p+1}(A^T)^{p+1}x = \|(A^T)^{p+1}x\|_2^2 \leq (\|A^T\|_2\|(A^T)^px\|_2)^2 \leq \|(A^T)^px\|_2^2 = x^TA^p(A^T)^px\,.$$
Using this and Courant-Fisher theorem (min-max theorem) we have
\begin{align}
  \lambda_i(A^{p+1}(A^T)^{p+1})
    &= \max_{\dim(U)=i}\;\min_{x\in U,\|x\|_2=1} x^TA^{p+1}(A^T)^{p+1}x \leq\\
    &\leq \max_{\dim(U)=i}\;\min_{x\in U,\|x\|_2=1} x^TA^p(A^T)^px = \lambda_i(A^p(A^T)^p)\,,
\end{align}
showing your claim was correct.

Comment: Yes, that seems right. So this also remains true for non-positive entries.

Comment: Yes, the proof is valid even if the entries of the matrix are not positive.